# Android: Convert Json string into List and vice versa

Tags: android, json, list

I was looking for an example and alive code to transfer just a list of objects into Json string and vice versa.
It is not a secret, that Androids are often used as a communication devices between (in my case) PC with .NET and the Android device itself.
The very common operation is to send SMS messages to a group of subscribers, that's usually exists as a List of objects.. say..

```
class Man { 
public string Number {get;set;} 
public string Message {get;set;} 
}
```

So, the `List<Man> Men = new List<Man>();`
is quite intuitive as the basic structure.

I can convert both ways in C#.NET

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
public static void Main() {
List<Man> Men = new List<Man>();
// numbers are just random
Man m1 = new Man();
m1.Number = "+6149168158";
m1.Message = "Hello Bob from 1";
m1.UniqueCode = "0123";
m1.State = 0;

Man m2 = new Man();
m2.Number = "+6146146182";
m2.Message = "Hello Bob from 2";
m2.UniqueCode = "0125";
m2.State = 0;

Men.AddRange(new Man[] { m1, m2 });

string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Men);
Console.WriteLine(result);

List<Man> men = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Man»(result);
foreach(Man m in men) Console.WriteLine(m.Message);
}
}
public class Man
{
public string Number{get;set;}
public string Message {get;set;}
public string UniqueCode {get;set;}
public int State {get;set;}
}
```

It works.. but the Android side.. just like a dark matter.. I am sure it exists, but I can't touch it..
So, please, whoever knows it, please, publish the Android part here, so the others would get nice and clear example for such a standard requirement.
(No Gson, Mason or some others.. only Android and only JSON..
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not want to use the tools available( Gson, Mason or some others..)
You must manually implement your mapper class for every object:
Native tools for android are JSONArray,JSONObject;
In the following code I have provided an example of decoding
Ok, this is the **Deserializator**

```
public List<Man> DecodeFactor(String json) throws JSONException {
    List<Man> list = null;
    try
    {
        JSONArray headarrays=new JSONArray(json);
        if(headarrays.length()>0)
        {
            list=new ArrayList<Man>();
            for (int i = 0; i <headarrays.length() ; i++)
            {
                Man man=new Man();
                JSONObject o = headarrays.getJSONObject(i);
                man.Message = o.getString("Message");
                man.Number = o.getString("Number");
                man.UniqueCode = o.getString("UniqueCode");
                man.State = o.getInt("State");
                list.add(man);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ee) { ee.printStackTrace(); }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. No. I would just happy to use any but I haven't seen any workable example, and also, knowing what the Reflection is, I was just wondering why Json doesn't offer this transformation automatically.. Type Man is and would be defined in Android Code, so I would just say do me the list of Man-objects, all names and values are in.. and know having your reply I understand that there is no such option, though in Gson under Java does it...

Comment: Actually, several months ago I was doing such mapper (I lost it somewhere), and I had one extra element in string list - type name.. So when I was recreating the structure, I knew the Type name and was able to create in and fill all the fields inside that mapper.. So user needn't care much about what is inside it. Thank you for your reply. It will be very useful, believe me.

Comment: Besides the fact that you decoding the JSON data in a `for` loop and yet still only extracting the Zero index JSON Object --> `new JSONObject(headarrays.getJSONObject(0).toString());` instead of using `i`, you are unnecessarily creating a new `JSONObject` when all you need to do is this:`JSONObject o = headarrays.getJSONObject(i);`